# Paypoint New Api Anatomy of a Payment Request

Tags: payment-gateway

Im trying to figure the format of a JSON request for payment to the new Paypoint API. The documentation is limited, I have no paypoint account, ive requested a demo. Can someone advise what the resource ID should be? Please also check the request to see if it is correct.

```
 var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.mite.paypoint.net:2443/acceptor/rest/transactions/{instId}/{resourceId}/action");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {

                string json = "{\"transaction\": {" +
                              "\"currency\": \"GBP\"," +
                              "\"amount\": \"1000.0\"," +
                              "\"description\": \"Example\"," +
                              "\"merchantRef\": \"mer_txn_1234557\"," +
                              "\"commerceType\": \"MOTO\" }}";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                streamWriter.Close();
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Op was about paypoint which is not PayPal.paypoint is s UK payment provider mainly used in pos situations

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using C#, you can using the .NET SDK available [here](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK) to build your request objects and collect the response. There are code samples here for nearly everything you can do with the new Paypal API.